# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Caught error after test environment was torn down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, jest-mock-axios

Get Error when test fails case in post request [image for Error when running test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo7Nb.png)

**Using Reactjs framework version 16**

**axios-hooks for api requests**

**react-testing-library for test**

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Caught error after test
> environment was torn down
>
> Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null (node:171)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)

**test code**

```
test('If user enters an invalid email or password', async () => {
  const { getByText, getByLabelText, getByTestId } = render(
    <Provider store={mockStore}>
      <Login />
    </Provider>
  )
  fireEvent.change(getByLabelText('Email'), {
    target: { value: 'test@emailing.com' }
  })
  fireEvent.change(getByLabelText('Password'), {
    target: { value: 'password' }
  })

  getByText('Sign in').click()
  await waitForDomChange()
  await act(async () => {
    try {
      await MockAxios.mockError({
        code: 400,
        data: {
          response: {
            data: {
              message: "This password is incorrect. Please re-enter your password."
            }
          }
        }

      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
  await waitForDomChange()
  expect(MockAxios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  await expect(getByTestId('error-msg')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

**(code is tested) Using axios hooks make request then send error to form**

```
 const [{ data, loading, error }, exec] = useAxios(
    {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'oauth/token/',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    },
    { manual: true }
  )  

return (
    <>
      {(loading || userDataLoading) && <Loader />}
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        error={error}
      />
    </>
  )
```

Comment: please include info what framework you are using and what you are trying to achieve. It will make it easier for other users to help you.

Comment: Using Reactjs framework version 16.
i try to test apost api and simulate theis req return error and error is handled

Comment: This happens to me as well, but only when a test before isn't finished on time and throws `async callback was not invoked...`